# Lipschitz Property of Matrix Mulitiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, continuity, linear-transformations, lipschitz-functions

Fix $x \in \mathbb{R}^{d_1}$ and define the map
$$
\begin{aligned}
F:\mathbb{R}^{d_1\times d_2 + d_2} & \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d_2}
\\
(A,b)&\mapsto Ax+b.
\end{aligned}
$$

Is this map Lipschitz?  It seems to me that it should be but I'm having trouble showing it....

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I played with Cauchy-Schwartz and I think the constant should be $\max\{1,\|x\|\}$ but maybe I'm wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We adopt in both ${\mathbb R}^{d_2\times d_1+d_2}$ and in ${\mathbb R}^{d-2}$ the euclidean metric $|\cdot|$ . It is well known that the operator norm $\|A\|:=\sup_{x\ne0}{|Ax|\over|x|}$  of a linear map $A$ with matrix $[a_{ik}]$ satisfies
$$\|A\|\leq |A|:=\left(\sum_{i, k}|a_{ik}^2|\right)^{1/2}\ .$$
This means  that $|Ax|\leq |A|\>|x|$ for all $x$.

Denote the given (fixed) vector in ${\mathbb R}^{d_1}$ by $c$ (instead of $x$). Let two points $(A,b)$, $(A',b')\in{\mathbb R}^{d_2\times d_1+d_2}$ be given. Then we have to look at
$$F(A,b)-F(A',b')=(A-A')c+(b-b')\ .\tag{1}$$
We have $|A-A'|\leq\bigl|(A,b)-(A',b')\bigr|\,$, and similarly for $|b-b'|$. From $(1)$ we therefore obtain
$$|F(A,b)-F(A',b')|\leq|A-A'|\>|c|+|b-b'|\leq\bigl|(A,b)-(A',b')\bigr|\ (|c|+1)\ .$$
This shows that $F$ is Lipschitz continuous with $|c|+1$ an acceptable Lipschitz constant.